# Can't understand why my custom type `DefaultProps` doesn't work well with `Pick`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a `DefaultProps` type which can finds all `Undefinable` properties from a given `Props` type of a react component, to help me to define defaultProps in a type safe manner:

```
export type UndefinableKeys<T> = Exclude<{
  [key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[key] ? key : never
} [keyof T], undefined>;

import {UndefinableKeys} from "./UndefinableKeys";

export type DefaultProps<T> = {
  [key in UndefinableKeys<T>]: Exclude<T[key], undefined>
}
```

Then I defined a helper function:

```
type OptionalPropsBuilder<P extends object> = {
  withAll: (defaultProps: DefaultProps<P>) => DefaultProps<P>;
  withSome: <DP extends Partial<DefaultProps<P>>>(defaultProps: DP) => Pick<DefaultProps<P>, keyof DP>;
};

export default function undefinableProps<P extends object>(): OptionalPropsBuilder<P> {
  return {
    withAll: (defaultProps) => defaultProps,
    withSome: (defaultProps) => defaultProps,
  };
}
```

Its usage will like:

```
type Props = {
  someProp1?: number,
  someProp2?: number
}

const allDefaultProps = undefinableProps<Props>().withAll({
  someProp1: 111,
  someProp2: 222
})

const someDefaultProps = undefinableProps<Props>().withAll({
  someProp1: 111,
  // someProp2: 222
})
```

But I found there is compilation errors on `withSome` method, and can't figure out why after several hours of debugging.

1. Why does `Pick<DefaultProps<P>, keyof DP>` have compilation error on the `keyof DP` part
2. I tried to change it to: `Pick<DefaultProps<P>, Extract<keyof DefaultProps<P>, keyof DP>>`, but it still have same compilation error

Comment: What if you change ```Pick<DefaultProps<P>, keyof DP>``` to ```Required<DP>```? I think it should work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Through all of the mapping typescript has lost the knowledge that `DP` is a subset of `P` and therefore keys of `DP` must also be keys of `P`.

This is all unnecessary though, because what is `Pick<DefaultProps<P>, Extract<keyof DefaultProps<P>, keyof DP>>` really?  It is the same as saying `DP`.  Just return `DP`.

Obviously your code isn't quite finished so I played around with it a bit more.

We define a `PropFiller` for the object `P` as a function which takes a set of valid `props: P` and returns a set of props that fulfills `P` and also adds some subset of the optional properties as required.

```
type PropFiller<P extends object, DP extends Partial<DefaultProps<P>>> = (props: P) => P & DP;
```

We implement this with a higher-order function that takes the set of `defaultProps: DP` and returns a `PropFiller<P, DP>` function.

```
const createPropFiller = <P extends object, DP extends Partial<DefaultProps<P>>>(defaultProps: DP): PropFiller<P, DP> => 
  (props: P) => ({
    ...defaultProps,
    ...props
  });
```

Our `OptionalPropsBuilder` type includes two cases of `createPropFiller`.  `withAll` requires that the `PropFiller` adds all `DefaultProps<P>` while `withSome` can take any subset.

```
type OptionalPropsBuilder<P extends object> = {
  withAll: (defaultProps: DefaultProps<P>) => PropFiller<P, DefaultProps<P>>;
  withSome: <DP extends Partial<DefaultProps<P>>>(defaultProps: DP) => PropFiller<P, DP>;
};

function undefinableProps<P extends object>(): OptionalPropsBuilder<P> {
  return {
    withAll: createPropFiller,
    withSome: createPropFiller,
  };
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/3NDV8W)